# SQL how to iterate through date in a nested query and then sum it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a working query in SQL that gets all the square footage of a building for each suite based on an effective date. After that I need to sum up the total square footage for each building.

Here's my working query.

```
SELECT suit.BLDGID, suit.SUITID
,COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 SQFT FROM MRI.SSQF SSQF WHERE suit.BLDGID = SSQF.BLDGID AND 
    SUIT.SUITID = SSQF.SUITID AND SSQF.EFFDATE <= '1/1/2014' ORDER BY EFFDATE DESC),0) AS 'NRASQFT'
FROM MRI.SUIT SUIT
```

Now the problem is that I need to iterate `SSQF.EFFDATE <= '1/1/2014'` throughout the year to 
`SSQF.EFFDATE <= '2/1/2014'` , `SSQF.EFFDATE <= '3/1/2014'` , `SSQF.EFFDATE <= '4/1/2014'` and etc..

Here's the SSQF table

```
BLDGID      SUITID      EFFDATE         SQFT
24931       0100        2013-03-31      6000.00
24931       0100        2013-12-01      5026.00
24931       0100        2014-01-01      5026.00
24931       0125        2013-12-02      5745.00
24931       0135        2013-12-02      3666.00
24931       0145        2013-12-02      3621.00
24931       0145        2013-12-31      3621.00
24931       0145        2014-01-01      3621.00
24931       0150        2013-12-02      6335.00
24931       0150        2013-12-31      6335.00
```

Here's the SUIT table

```
BLDGID      SUITID
24931       0100      
24931       0125      
24931       0135      
24931       0145      
24931       0150
```

I had to join the Suit table in order to get only 1 count of square footage for each suit.

Here's the Output of the working query.

```
BLDGID      SUITID      NRASQFT
24931       0100        5026.00
24931       0125        5745.00
24931       0135        3666.00
24931       0145        3621.00
24931       0150        6335.00
```

After that, I need to sum up the total square footage based on the BLDGID.

How do I go about writing the summation effectively and iterating though the dates?

The final output is putting the total square footage of each month into a table like this.

```
BLDGID  YearDesc    January     February    March       April       May         June        July        August      September   October     November    December
24931   2014        371478.00   381526.00   381526.00   381526.00   381526.00   381526.00   381526.00   381526.00   381526.00   381526.00   381526.00   381526.00
```

Comment: This is Microsoft SQL Server right? If so, why have you tagged MySql?

Comment: Sorry, went back and updated it. it's in SQL server. using 2012

Comment: And yet you still have [tag:sql-server-2008] tagged! :)

Comment: What should the output be?

Comment: updated with output data

Comment: BTW, never iterate through rows if you can avoid it and you can most of the time (Inmy experience over 95%). Forget you ever even heard the concept of iterating through rows. You should act on sets of data in databases not iterate.

Answer (score 1):

Add all the month names in the IN clause and in select column list, i have added only Jan, Feb, March

```
SELECT bldgid, YearDesc, [January], [Febraury], [March]
FROM
(
select SSQ.bldgid, SUM(sqft) as totalSqft ,DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, SSQ.effdate), 0)) as dateval,
DATENAME(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, SSQ.effdate), 0)) AS YearDesc
from ssqf SSQ
INNER JOIN suit ST
on SSQ.suitid = ST.suitid
and SSQ.bldgid = ST.bldid
group by SSQ.bldgid, DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, SSQ.effdate), 0)),
DATENAME(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, SSQ.effdate), 0))
) as BD
PIVOT
(
    max(totalSqft) for dateval in ( [January], [Febraury], [March])
) pvt
```